# Too many native crashes on Google Play Dev Console

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am seeing too many native crashes on Google Play Dev console. The crashes started coming when I integrated Android WorkManager into my app. Before the WorkManager update, there was not a single native crash with my app, but as of now with current production version I see about 100 native crashes.

My app makes use of `NotificationListener` and periodic network active which is handled by WorkManager.

[image]